# I got an error immediately after login into ubuntu

Tags: locale

[image: The image contains actual error]

I don't know what went wrong but I stuck into this difficult situation
where I login into system and immediately I get this message as shown into image. I did try every possible solution on internet, but got nothing more than disappointment. I am a newbie. Hope I will find solution.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?. Have you recently downgraded from a higher version? Please have a look at this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/+bug/1837300

Comment: I didn't changed any version in ubuntu.

Comment: Hmm.. I'd say that the message tells you in cleartext what the problem is: The file `/usr/bin/locale-check` is not present for some reason. You should be able to get it by running this command: `sudo apt install --reinstall base-files`

Comment: Thank you very much brother it did worked for me!